# Creating Sub Arrays with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Not having much luck creating a sub array, partially because I don't fully grasp how keys work.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
$sql = "select * from products";
$db->query($sql);
$products = $db->rows();

foreach($products as $key=>$row) {

    $sql = "select * from sub_products WHERE productid = " . (int)$row['ID'] . "";
    $db->query($sql);
    $subproducts = $db->rows();

    $products[$key]['subproducts'] = $subproducts;

    foreach($products[$key]['subproducts'] as $rr=>$x) {

        $sql = "select * from subsubproducts WHERE subproducts = " . (int)$x['ID'] . "";
        $db->query($sql);
        $subsubproducts = $db->rows();

        $products[$key]['subproducts']['subsubproducts'] = $subsubproducts;
    }

}
```

I am not really grasping the concept of keys here and so therefore I am having a hard time understanding how to insert sub-arrays into other sub-arrays.

Currently, the code above, instead of placing the subsubproducts array as an array/item within the subproducts array, it is tagging it on as another item/array.  i.e. under subproducts you have:

subproduct1
subproduct2
subsubproducts

Whereas it should be:

subproduct1
---subsubproductslisting

subproduct2
---subsubproductslisting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it you just need to do replace this:

`$products[$key]['subproducts']['subsubproducts'] = $subsubproducts;`

with this:

`$products[$key]['subproducts'][$rr]['subsubproducts'] = $subsubproducts;`

In the second foreach loop

Answer (score 2):

If I follow your train of thought, it should be as easy as identifying the key and using  it in the second loop to identify the correct array.

```
    $products[$key]['subproducts'][ $rr ]['subsubproducts'] = $subsubproducts;
```

In context:

```
$sql = "select * from products";
$db->query($sql);
$products = $db->rows();

foreach($products as $key=>$row) {

    $sql = "select * from sub_products WHERE productid = " . (int)$row['ID'] . "";
    $db->query($sql);
    $subproducts = $db->rows();

    $products[$key]['subproducts'] = $subproducts;

    foreach($products[$key]['subproducts'] as $rr=>$x) {

        $sql = "select * from subsubproducts WHERE subproducts = " . (int)$x['ID'] . "";
        $db->query($sql);
        $subsubproducts = $db->rows();

        $products[$key]['subproducts'][ $rr ]['subsubproducts'] = $subsubproducts;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are properly adding depth to the arrays, your logical context is just off.

`foreach($products[$key]['subproducts'] as $key=>$row)` will assign the index to `$key` and the value to `$row` for each iteration.

`foreach($products[$key]['subproducts'] as $rr => $x)` will assign the index to `$rr` and the value to `$x` for each iteration.

When you assign to `$products[$key]['subproducts']['subsubproducts']` you are assigning a value to the key `subsubproducts` at the `subproducts` level.

Changing the assignment to:

```
$products[$key]['subproducts'][$rr]['subsubproducts'] = $subsubproducts;
```

should give you the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information Steve.  Once I saw it on Jeffan's answer it made sense to me.